# Is it okay for multiple computers write data with PowerShell to a single file in one remote computer?

Tags: powershell

I am writing some powershell scripts running on Hyper-V clusters to retrieve VM statistics in each host in the clusters and writes the data to a HTML file in a master server, using `Add-Content` cmdlets. Based on the number of virtual machines, each cluster needs 20 to 30 minutes to finish writing.

What I'm curious about is whether the master server can hold those multiple connections. Retrieving data itself is not an issue, because the process runs on each cluster. But I'm afraid of possible crashes or something because of concurrent connections from multiple servers to a single file. CPU and memory resources of the master server are enough, of course.

May I let the programs on the clusters run at once, or do I have to make some intervals between the servers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many VMs are we talking about? How much data per VM? Up to thirty minutes sounds so long a time that the process is extremely inefficient, unless the file is in multi-gigabyte range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often a bad idea to allow simultaneous write operations by multiple processes into one file. Allowing such a process requires careful planning. Usually a [write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) is acquired so only one process can update the file at a time. Without one, the processes can write into the file so that the result is a big mess. Processes P and Q write content with locking like so,

```
p p p
q q q
q q q
p p p
```

All's well and neat. Now, let's allow multiple writes and we might - might, there are no guarantees here! - get data like so,

```
p p q q q 
p
q q q
p p p
```

What happened here is that after two `p` writes, `q` writes three times and adds a newline. Now the file structure is already broken with five entries on a line. Then the third `p` is written with a newline. Oops, only one entry on a line. Then the processes resume writing and by a mere chance, two next lines are written in proper an order.

The correct way is to acquire a lock so that only one process can update the file at a time.

Comment: I think I've got to find some way to lock the process. Thank you for a nice answer.

Comment: Multiple writers is a [well-researched problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) and thus many solutions already exist. For example, invert the control. Make the clusters produce a log file with, say, cluster name and timestamp in filename. Then push the logs to your control server and use control server to combine the logs when all have arrived.